# Comparing two integers in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to compare two sets of digits. The first I will generate as a random in code. The second will be entered into an EditText.

I wish to compare the two numbers and see if they match.

Random number:

```
public static int random() {
   if (randomNumberGenerator == null)
      initRNG();

   return randomNumberGenerator.nextInt();
}

private static Random randomNumberGenerator;
private static synchronized void initRNG() {
   if (randomNumberGenerator == null)
      randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
}
```

Showing randomly selected number

```
display = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
display.setText ("Random Number:" + random ());
```

How can I compare the two numbers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just make a subtraction between both numbers and if the result is 0, both numbers match.

EDIT: Subtraction was just a way to show that both were numbers. Obviously it makes more sense to compare both numbers directly rather than subtracting and comparing then.

Comment: And how to pull a digit from EditText?

Comment: It depends on the type of number. For an integer: int value = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString())

Comment: Then compare both strings.
String matchingNumber = "12345ABC";
if(editText.getText().toString().equals(matchingNumber))

Comment: No prob, happy to help, although the vote and the tick went to an incomplete answer. This world... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following:

```
display = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
EditText myEditText = ...; // Find your EditText, maybe by ID?
int random = random(); // Get your random value
display.setText("Random Number:" + random()); // Show the random number
int numberEntered = -1; // Default value for numberEntered; should be a value you wouldn't get randomly
try {
    // Here, we try to make a number out of the EditText; if it fails, we get a Toast error
    numberEntered = Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    Toast.makeText(myEditText.getContext(), "That's not a number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Tell the user they didn't enter a number
}
if (random == numberEntered) {
    // HAPPY DAY, THEY MATCH!
} else {
    // No luck :(
}
```